# CURL POST Login and Redirect appears to not be working

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a short PHP plugin for a WordPress site, the goal of which is to hook onto a Javascript-generated A tag, CURL a POST request to a different website which Logs the user into that site, and then redirects the user to a page on that site.

The idea is that the user would click on the A tag on the wordpress site and the script would log them in and redirect so that they don't have to enter the login credentials themselves; the login would already have been performed by the curl.

When I test this out, only the redirect portion of the script occurs. The login doesn't appear to occur; or, if it does, it doesn't appear to 'stick'; maybe something is happening with the cookie so that the login isn't remembered. I'm not sure how to debug this because the Network tab under Chrome DevTools is empty, and the Debug Log in WordPress' file manager is not showing any errors either.

Here is my script:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Denrile's Plogger
Plugin URI: http://my-awesomeness-emporium.com
description: >- a plugin to that takes the user to the Pruvan website,
after using CURL to log them in so that the redirect doesn't hit a user authentication wall.
Version: 1.0
Author: John Mauran
Author URI: http://github.com/jmauran91
License: GPL2
*/



  function loginToJulian($url, $username, $password){
    $curl = curl_init();
    $header[0]= "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $verbose = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
    // Make the errors visible in a new file

    $payload_username = '"'.$username.'"';
    $payload_password = '"'.$password.'"';
    $payloadtext=urlencode('{"username":'.$payload_username.',"password":'.$payload_password.'}');
    $payload = "payload=".$payloadtext;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    header("Location: https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/pmgr");

  }

  function default_wordpress_hook(){
    $j_username = "Denrile";
    $j_password = "***********";
    $login_url ="https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/login?redir=%2Fv2%2Fpmgr&m=Authentication%20Required";
    $last_url = "https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/pmgr";

    if(isset($_GET['prvn_login'])){
      loginToJulian($login_url, $j_username, $j_password);
      exit();
    } else {

    }
  }

  add_action("init","default_wordpress_hook");

?>
```

Helpful suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

EDITED: ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login to the site, the *browser* must make an HTTP request to it and receive the cookie data that marks them as logged in in the response.

When you make the request with cURL, you get the cookie in the server side code, and it never reaches the browser, so the browser isn't logged in.

Note that your website *cannot* set cookies in the browser on behalf of the other website.

Comment: So it seems you're saying that the approach I've chosen won't work. Do you have some suggestions as to what to do instead?

Comment: Use a tool like 1Password or (if you control all the sites involved) research how standard Single Sign On system work.

Comment: I don't control any of the sites involved. Does this close off my options?

Comment: @John - Yes. Use a tool like 1Password instead.